# search multidimensional array on string to check if related words exists php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make a verb searcher inside a text.

```
$conjugation=array();
$conjugation[0]=array("sein","bin","bist","ist","war","gewesen");
$conjugation[1]=array("haben","habe","hast","hat","hatte","gehabt");
$conjugation[2]=array("lesen","lese","liest","liest","las","gelesen");
$conjugation[3]=array("gehen","gehe","geht","gehts","ging","gegangen");
```

I want to search each verb conjugation inside the text and retrieve it with replaced conjugated verbs

```
  $string="Ich habe das Buch gelesen. Du hast einen apfel. Sie ist nicht gegangen";

  ...<span title='gehen'>gegangen</span>...
```

to check that this conjugation belongs to the verb...

I was thinking using `in_array()` to search for them but I cant get the results as expected...

```
$words = split(" ", $string); 
$searchWords = $conjugation[0];


  for($x = 0,$l = $count; $x < $l;) { 

  echo $words[$x++]." ";

    if(in_array($words[$x++], $searchWords)) {
        $word1=$x - 1;
            echo "<span title='$verb[0]'> $words[$word1]"."</span>";
    }
  }
```

**How would I get what expected?**

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 Ich <span title='haben'>habe</span> das Buch 
 <span title='lesen'>gelesen</span>. 
 Du <span title='haben'>hast</span> einen apfel. 
 Sie <span title='sein'>ist</span> nicht <span title='gehen'>gegangen</span>
```

Comment: You're incrementing `$x` when you call `in_array`, so you're echoing the next word.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output is?

Comment: How is `$verb` related to this?

Comment: I already update and posted the expected result

Comment: Why are you only searching `$conjugation[0]`? `habe` is in `$conjugation[1]`.

Comment: Why don't you create an associative array whose keys are the conjugations and values are the verbs?

Comment: I updated again...I tried to create an associative. but it would be a new array, so I would have to work with three arrays...

Comment: Where did the `$verb` array go? My answer is based on that version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to look for any of these words and replace them with the appropriate `<span>`:

```
foreach ($conjugation as $verbConjugations) {
  $pattern = '/\b(?<word>' . implode('|', $verbConjugations) . ')\b/i';
  $string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($verbConjugations) {
    return "<span title='{$verbConjugations[0]}'>{$matches['word']}</span>";
  }, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/AiJE9**

Comment: wow It seems a pretty good code..but for some reason it doesnt work in my laptop server. I think I have an old php version...t would be a way to rewrite it to match with old php?

Comment: besides now deleted the array `$verb` and add it the main verb in the first field of every subarray. (I edited the post)

Comment: @max Updated the answer and switched back to old array style. If it still doesn't work, it means you're running PHP 5.3 or below and that's waaaayyyy too old (PHP 5 itself isn't recommended, especially older versions of it).

Comment: Its just a own server where I currently use to learn lenguages...so...I your code doesnt work here. is there any way the make it fit to the version? I think the problem is this function `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: @max What error are you getting? If it's a practice server to learn languages, you should definitely upgrade to newer PHP versions though.

Comment: @max https://3v4l.org/5cIDN Does this version work? It's PHP4-compliant, so I won't put that in the answer, because that should never be public :)

Comment: Im trying ...its 5.x.x ...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: @max Are you sure you tried [this version](https://3v4l.org/5cIDN)? I haven't edited the answer. Click the link in my comment.

Comment: My friend. the last demo you sent me works perfectly. Your code its just awesome!!

Comment: @max Nice. But again, if you're learning, you should *strongly* consider upgrading your PHP version one of these days. Good luck.

Comment: one only thing. the code doesnt recognize if in the text there is the infinitive verb like `haben` that i the first valur of each array

Comment: now it does. changing the 1 value to 0 in `array_slice($verbConjugations, 0)` thank you very much. you have helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array that maps the conjugations to their verbs. Then use that to create the replacements.

```
$verb_map = array();
foreach ($verb as $i => $v) {
    foreach ($conjugation[$i] as $w) {
        $verb_map[$w] = $v;
    }
}
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$new_words = array();
foreach ($words as $w) {
    $lower_word = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', strtolower($w));
    if (isset($verb_map[$lower_word])) {
        $new_words[] = "<span title='{$verb_map[$lower_word]}'>$w</span>";
    } else {
        $new_words[] = $w;
    }
}
$new_string = implode(' ', $new_words);
echo $new_string;
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/U4umDB)

And in general, you should avoid creating multiple arrays with related data. Combine them into a multi-dimensional array:

```
$verbs = array(
    array("verb" => "haben", "conjugation" => array("habe","hast","hat","hatte","gehabt")),
    array("verb" => "sein", "conjugation" => array("bin","bist","ist","war","gewesen")),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Im testing but it doesnt retrieve words with titles

Comment: You need to convert the word to lowercase before searching for it. I've added that.

Comment: `[...]` just becomes `array(...)`

Comment: It doesnt recognize. `gelesen` because it has a dot (.) besides

Comment: I've added `preg_replace` to remove all non-letters from the word.

Comment: it still doesnt